# Barcode implementation on Android

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode

I want to make an Android app that uses the camera to take a photo of a barcode for a product to get the number of barcode, but I have some problem to make the implementation.

The main question is how can I use the camera to take a picture to recognize the id of this barcode without using any external application.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Android has no native barcode recognition facilities. Barcode reader apps in the market do their own image recognition to "read" barcodes. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240341/reading-barcodes-with-android

Comment: Start here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Answer (score 3):

You should try Zxing library, the library contains Barcode Scanning feature.

here : http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you use the external application? This is the power of Android apps - they can use each other functionality, which is implemented perfectly in their app.

Answer (score 0):

yes yu should use the zxing tool this is an open source you can use in your code too, here : http://code.google.com/p/zxing/
downloads/list.    download the source code from main site and see manual it will give you the instruction too