# Scanning QR codes using OpenCV and Zxing for Android

Tags: android, opencv, zxing

I am using OpenCV (2.4.8) and Zxing (2.3.0) for Android and I'd like implement „hidden“ QR code scanning (without use Zxing `CaptureActivity` on screen) in `Mat` converted to bitmap and then display decoded result in console.

So, I call `Zxing()` methot in `onCameraFrame` method:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    // there will be preprocessing
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    try {
        zxing();
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return mRgba;
}
```

And it is my `zxing()` method (inspired by [ZXing convert Bitmap to BinaryBitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861553/zxing-convert-bitmap-to-binarybitmap)):

```
public void zxing() throws ChecksumException, FormatException{

    Bitmap bMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.width(), mRgba.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bMap);
    int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()];  
    //copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array  
    bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());  

    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(),intArray);

    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
    Reader reader = new QRCodeMultiReader();     

    String sResult = "";

   try {

        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);   
        sResult = result.getText();
        Log.d(TAG, sResult);

        }
    catch (NotFoundException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Code Not Found");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

With this code, I receive "Code Not Found" messages (about five per second) in LogCat console when camera don’t capture QR code, but when try scan QR code, I don’t see any message ( I thought I will receive sResult).
What I have wrong?

Android manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="mk.app_02_28.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was stupid mistake, I had wrong line

```
Log.d(TAG, sResult);
```

It should be:

```
Log.d(TAG,"Found something: "+result.getText());
```