# QR code scan from image file

Tags: java, android, zxing, qr-code, zbar

Tried to use several libraries like ZXing, ZBar and their forks but didn't find way to scan barcode not from camera but from file.

Can someone point me to right direction? Preferably I'm looking into ZXing: how to scan image from file (not from camera).

Please.

Comment: may be this will help http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/11/reading-quick-response-codeqr-in-java.html

Comment: Not sure whether this example workable under Android - but let me try

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the end I've found solution. Code is (originated from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861553/zxing-convert-bitmap-to-binarybitmap)):

```
import com.google.zxing.*;

public static String scanQRImage(Bitmap bMap) {
    String contents = null;

    int[] intArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()];
    //copy pixel data from the Bitmap into the 'intArray' array
    bMap.getPixels(intArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());

    LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), intArray);
    BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

    Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
    try {
        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
        contents = result.getText();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("QrTest", "Error decoding barcode", e);
    }
    return contents;
}
```

Gradle referencing as:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
}
```

Usage:

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
String decoded=scanQRImage(bitmap);
Log.i("QrTest", "Decoded string="+decoded);
```

Comment: @barmley, any idea how to do it with zbar

Comment: Thanks, it does work for copied qrcode. But if i m trying to scan a photo it is not recognized although the image looks very good to me. 
Is there any chance to make it recognize real pics? Adjusting Quality or some filters or something?