# Adding dependencies to platform specific code in Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter

I'm trying to implement the code from answer #1 from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32134072/qr-code-scan-from-image-file) thread in Flutter.

The "invokeMethod" is correctly set and the Android gets correctly called.
When I try to add the specific code that should come from the library "com.google.zxing", I don't understand how to import it.

I tried putting it into the Android gradle, but the zxing class methods remain "red" in MainActivity, as the library doesn't get imported.

Maybe there is a specific procedure to import external dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had to import it this way in the class:

```
 import com.google.zxing.*;
 import com.google.zxing.common.*;
```

As the object "HybridBinarizer" is defined in the second one, and couldn't be retrieved otherwise.

As of the gradle, I had to add the dependency this way:

```
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
}
```

in the file *project/android/build.gradle*, similar to the traditional Android way but using classpath instead of compile.

Another thing, a method of the zxing library (i.e. Result) was giving an error since the Result class was already defined in another library (*io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result*).

I solved this problem by creating a separate Java class and simply putting all the zxing methods there.

Answer (score 0):

if you're write a flutter plugin and want to add dependency to your android side you have to go to your `build.gradle` file and add `dependencies` block below the `android` block

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
    }
}

// you're dependencies block are here and put you're dependency inside it like you would in any normal android project

dependencies {
    // your dependency here
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.1'

}
```