# I want to make an application which reads qr code but it should not use any external application

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to make an application which reads qr code but it should not use any external application
i had tried with zxing code but some times it cant read codes

thanks in advance

Comment: `some times it cant read codes` I sincerely doubt there's anything out there that has a 100% success rate, considering lighting conditions and camera resolution can vary greatly in different scenarios.

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240341/reading-barcodes-with-android

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at the following ZBar library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/.